# Why does deleting blob in azure resulted to StorageRequest.materializeException()?

Tags: android, azure-blob-storage

I am using azure storage to backup images to blobs. Storing and downloading is happening, but when i will try to delete the blob, it resulting with following exception, how to resolve it?

```html
12-30 11:32:11.478: W/System.err(21160): com.microsoft.azure.storage.StorageException: Access Denied
12-30 11:32:11.479: W/System.err(21160):  at com.microsoft.azure.storage.core.StorageRequest.materializeException(StorageRequest.java:306)
12-30 11:32:11.479: W/System.err(21160):  at com.microsoft.azure.storage.core.ExecutionEngine.executeWithRetry(ExecutionEngine.java:176)
12-30 11:32:11.479: W/System.err(21160):  at com.microsoft.azure.storage.blob.CloudBlob.delete(CloudBlob.java:999)
12-30 11:32:11.479: W/System.err(21160):  at com.microsoft.azure.storage.blob.CloudBlob.deleteIfExists(CloudBlob.java:1060)
12-30 11:32:11.479: W/System.err(21160):  at com.microsoft.azure.storage.blob.CloudBlob.deleteIfExists(CloudBlob.java:1021)
12-30 11:32:11.479: W/System.err(21160):  at com.maraj.deletblob.Communication.send(Communication.java:39)
12-30 11:32:11.479: W/System.err(21160):  at com.maraj.deletblob.MainActivity$MyTask.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:33)
12-30 11:32:11.479: W/System.err(21160):  at com.maraj.deletblob.MainActivity$MyTask.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:1)
```

Comment: Materialize exception is the name of the method used to process the exception returned by the service. In order to debug this further, could you provide the code snippet which produces the problem?

Comment: This exception is occuring when i test with lollipop version of android, for other version delete blob method is working fine..i need to know the reason why its not working in lollipop version. and am using microsoft-azure-storage-android project as dependency for my android project.

Answer (score 0):

Versions 0.4.0 and older of the [Azure Storage Client Library for Android](https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-android) will not work with Android 5.0+ (Lollipop) due to a breaking change in the Android platform. Using these versions with Android 5.0+ will result in authentication failures for blob, queue, and file deletes. Upgrading to [version 0.4.1](https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-android/releases)+ of the storage client library should resolve this issue.

Comment: Its working fine, may i know this issue is occurring for os version change?